# MYSQL database proper design and performance issue (normalization - varchar as key)

Tags: mysql, normalization, database-normalization

I have a table Xdata with five columns

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(15) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| for_id     | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dom_attr   | varchar(350)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| domain     | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dom_hash   | binary(16)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table is being populated using 300 PHP process running in parallel 24/7, each process insert 100 record per run and consume approximate 1 sec, I created dom_hash as a key for domain column using unhex(md5(domain)) to fast select related domain rows by passing specific domain to where clause

After a couple of days the size exceeded its limits, so i started looking into data normalization and found that selecting **distinct** dom_hash resulting into 30% of all rows,

My question is can i create another domain_key table (dom_hash,domain) and start add distinct domain to it and use it as a key, while adding only dom_hash as a foreign key in Xdata table ? this way i will have only dom_hash key repeated in Xdata table and not consuming this huge space that domain uses ? (considering that i will do the same with dom_attr as i have same above case for it)

When proceeding with that solution what would be the fast way to check of key exist in domain_key and insert new ones if not exists considering that single process will pass 100 domain each run (with 300 php process thats 30,000 check per sec), Time is very important factor during selecting the appropriate approach so if checking key existing process will consume time we will proceed with space waste denormalization as alternative (current approach).

i already tested exist and simple where query for key check, its working fine with only one php process, not sure how it will do with all three hundred process running same time, really appreciate your feedback

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM domain_key WHERE domain_key = unhex(md5(domain)))
SELECT dom_hash FROM domain_key WHERE domain_key = unhex(md5(domain))
```

Comment: Why are you creating a hash field instead of using the native HASH index from mysql? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: to maintain a small sized key